# TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
import inspect

import math

print(inspect.getsource(round))

TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method
```

why am i getting this error. How should i find the source code of this round function ?

I have tried to get the source code of round function in math module using inspect module in python, But I got module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method error after running the code. I am expecting to get the source code of round function in module math.

Comment: `round`, like all of the built-in functions, is written in C.  The `inspect` module can't reach them.  You'll have to go to the git repository for Python itself to see the source.  And, by the way, `round` is not part of the `math` module.  It's built-in.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim commented:

You can't access the source of builtins and other modules that were written using the C API, since there isn't a Python source for them.

From the documentation for inspect:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile

> Return the name of the Python source file in which an object was defined or None if no way can be identified to get the source. This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function.

You'll have to go to the git repository for Python itself to see the source for round.